# Handling multiple authentications with different credentials when using HtmlUnitDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, basic-authentication

I have a situation where my selenium test should handle different Authentication Windows with different credentials. I am using HtmlUnitDriver in java. Can someone provide a sample code to do this?
I know we can use DefaultCredentialsProvider, but can we add multiple credentials to it? Will it handle the Authentications automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you could provide the code you have so far and be a bit more specific about what is going wrong, it would be easier to provide a useful answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver() {
    protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {

        DefaultCredentialsProvider creds = new DefaultCredentialsProvider();
        // set the credentials
        creds.addCredentials("username", "password");

        // set the provider
        client.setCredentialsProvider(creds);

        return client;
    }
};
```